# Why does library(gganimate) give an error that is "No renderer backend detected. gganimate will default..."?

Tags: ggplot2

The code is:

```
library(gganimate)
```

Message:No renderer backend detected. gganimate will default to writing frames to separate files
Consider installing:

- the `gifski` package for gif output
- the `av` package for video output
  and restarting the R session

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do need install the packages:
install.packages("gifsski")
install.packages("av")